# Broken XML tag in Oracle table

Tags: xml, oracle, tags

I have a XML column in my table on a Oracle database, and for some reason, I realised that the XML tags are broken at the end.

```
<XMLBegin><linesandlinesofXML>blahblahblah</linesandlinesofXML>
<Framework.DesktopContent.ImageLocation ObjectName="PaneContentImageSelected" locati...
```

Can I know if it's possible to search for the "..." in a XML column where the "..." is not in a tag? I will like to weed out the broken XML and not have to purge the entire table.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is it that the xml is syntatically invalid and you want to find all non-syntactically valid XMLS (if so i'm assuming your column is CLOB/varchar2 typed rather than XMLType)

Comment: Yup, the XML column is CLOB (for history's sake).

Answer (score 3):

if its finding and Invalid XMLs, you can do this:

```
SQL> desc myxml
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- --------
 XML                                                CLOB

SQL> create or replace function is_valid(xml clob) return varchar2
  2  is
  3    e_invalid exception;
  4    pragma exception_init(e_invalid, -31011);
  5    v_xml xmltype;
  6  begin
  7    v_xml := xmltype(xml);
  8    return 'Y';
  9  exception
 10    when e_invalid
 11    then
 12      return 'N';
 13  end;
 14  /

Function created.

SQL> select * from myxml;

XML
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<XMLBegin><linesandlinesofXML>blahblahblah</linesandlinesofXML>
<Framework.DesktopContent.ImageLocation ObjectName="PaneContentImageSelected" lo
cati..

<XMLBegin><linesandlinesofXML>blahblahblah</linesandlinesofXML></XMLBegin>

SQL> select * from myxml where is_valid(xml) = 'N';

XML
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<XMLBegin><linesandlinesofXML>blahblahblah</linesandlinesofXML>
<Framework.DesktopContent.ImageLocation ObjectName="PaneContentImageSelected" lo
cati..
```

Comment: Wow! This is a pretty nice piece for everyone working on XML out there! Thanks, @DazzaL!